# Php using a variable on other pages through sessions

Tags: php, html, authentication, session-variables

Hello guys i have a problem with php sessions. I try to send a variable from my second page to my third page but i keep getting undefined variable i will include code from all three pages i am sorry in advance for the pretty large amount of code but i belive it will be easier for you guys to help then. Thanks in advance

PAGE 1

```
<form method="POST" action="authorize.php">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="username"><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="password"><br>
            <label for ="remeberMe">Remember me!</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remeberMe" class="rememberMe"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submitLogin" class="submitLogin" value="Login!">
        </form>
```

PAGE 2

```
    session_start();
    include 'connection.php';

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE screename = '$user' AND ...");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

    if ($count == 1)
    {
        $login = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $login = false;
    }   

    if ($login == true)
    {
        $_SESSION['access'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; 
        header("Location:"."mainpage.php?".SID);
        exit;
    }   
    else 
    {
        header("Location:"."index.php?");
        exit;
    }
```

PAGE 3

```
    session_start();

    if($_SESSION['access'] != true)
    {
        include("index.php");
        exit;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
    }
```

**ERROR:** `$user` on page 3 is undefined

Comment: Sidenote: This line is unfinished `$sql = mysqli_query($con,...` - bad paste?

Comment: Which file is `authorize.php`? And which values/ variables you want to pass torught which files?

Comment: `$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE screename = '$user' AND   ` .... is that your code?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry it was a bad paste it is finished in code :)

Comment: edit it........ also mention, __what undefined variable__

Comment: @Rizier123 authorize.php is page2 i want to pass username on to page 3 :)

Comment: it says that $user on page 3 is undefined

Comment: Use `$_SESSION['username']` instead of `$_POST['username']` in file 3 then it should work fine

Comment: Try replacing `$_POST['username']` with `$_SESSION['username']` on Page 3.

Comment: On you 'page 3', you will definitely get  `undefined variable` error at the line `if($_SESSION['access'] != true)` if `if ($login == true)` on 'page 2' was not executed

Comment: @Rizier123 nope :( still undefined..

Comment: @Anoxy what you get if you echo `$count` ? Try to `LIMIT 1` your sql statement or change the condition to `>=`

Comment: Edit your question, it's throwing off syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- [Pending suggested edit for that](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6207461)

Comment: @Rizier123 i get 1 if i echo $count :)

Comment: @AeroX I saw that. Sometimes when there's info missing from a query, could have *some* bearing on the outcome. For instance, if the missing query code is like `WHERE screename = '$user' AND column = '".$_SESSION['var']."'` (wink). I just like to see all the parts.

Comment: @Anoxy Are you sure header to page 3 get executed or do you stay at page 2 and don't even get to page 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you have to limit your SQL Statement with `LIMIT 1` or change this condition to `>=`:

```
if ($count == 1) //'>='
{
    $login = true;
}
else
{
    $login = false;
}
```

After that you have to change on page 3 this to the `$_SESSION` array:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) //to `$_SESSION['username']`
{
    $user = $_POST['username']; //to `$_SESSION['username']`
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect thanks! and thanks to everyone else that contributed! if you dont mind me asking why did i made a difference that i changed it to >=1  ? :)

Comment: If your not limiting your query the count could be 2 or 3 so the condition to == 1 wouldn't be true! So if you change it to >= your sure that the query has at min. 1 row or more!

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing a `POST` variable rather than the one you saved in your session.  Change to:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The undefined variable, are you referring to the $_POST['username'] or the session variable in page 3? The post variable would not be retained in page 3, you need to refer to the session variable $_SESSION['username'].